# Parsing large XML documents with Nokogiri vs Libxml2

Tags: c, xml, xslt, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I'm working on transforming a ~3GB XML document, structured as a list of similar `<Element>`. The document is too large to XSL transform directly. But each `<Element>` can be transformed independently, so I'm parsing the XML and separating them.

When testing with Nokogiri, I found performance quickly climbed into multiple minutes. As a test, I wrote an example parser in C using libxml2 directly, which is much faster.

Code and results:
https://gist.github.com/adilosa/d4277dc1c683da91990515352ffe5420

Is it reasonable to expect 10x overhead with Nokogiri vs C? Is it worth it then to handle large documents in C?

Comment: *"I know the code isn't equivalent..."* Both code samples have to produce same output or benchmark comparison is pointless. *"Is it worth it then to handle large documents in C? "* We cannot answer that. It's your call to make while evaluating all factors that are important to you.

Comment: I meant equivalent in terms of implementation, like not using dynamic lists, etc. They produce the same output.

Comment: In that case, choose between code simplicity and speed, which ever matters more. You also asked why the speed difference, but I doubt that anyone here will take time to perform detailed analysis, considering that there are external libraries and VM involved. That being said, it is very common to do quick prototype in higher level language first, and then faster version in lower level language.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". The minimal example code must be in the question itself, not a link. Links rot then break making the question nonsensical. DOM parsing of big files requires Nokogiri to load it into memory which can kill speed if the file won't fit into RAM. In that case a SAX parser will be faster as line-by-line I/O is fast.